# How To Tell If a MSSQL 2008 Database Has Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) Enabled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Does anyone happen to know if there is a way via WMI to tell whether a MSSQL 2008 database has TDE enabled?  We have a large SQL estate that I'd like to survey and find out where we have TDE enabled.  We have a nice WMI browser that can be scripted against across the enterprise so if there was some type of setting we could see from there, that would be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [sys.dm_database_encryption_keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677274.aspx) DMV.